# Grouping spark dataframe rows based on two sets of columns

Tags: python, pyspark

In the dataframe shown below, the rows should be grouped when either `(root,ext)` is the same or `(fname,lname,dob)` is the same.  Hoping to get ideas for pyspark code which would do this efficiently since there are over 10million records in the table.

Input

```
import datetime as dt

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("root",T.StringType()), T.StructField("ext",T.StringType()),
      T.StructField("fname",T.StringType()), T.StructField("lname",T.StringType()),
      T.StructField("dob",T.DateType())
  ])
key1 = schema.fieldNames()[:2]
key2 = schema.fieldNames()[2:]

sdf = (
  sqlContext.createDataFrame([
      ['A','B','C','D',dt.date(1980,1,1)],
      ['A','B','E','F',dt.date(1980,1,1)],
      ['G','H','C','D',dt.date(1980,1,1)],
      
      ['M','N','C','F',dt.date(1978,6,1)],
      ['P','H','C','F',dt.date(1978,6,1)],
      ['M','H','C','F',dt.date(1978,6,1)],
      ['M','N','X','F',dt.date(1978,6,1)],
    ], schema)
    .withColumn("id", F.row_number().over(W.orderBy(key1+key2)))
  )
sdf.show()

# +----+---+-----+-----+----------+---+
# |root|ext|fname|lname|       dob| id|
# +----+---+-----+-----+----------+---+
# |   A|  B|    C|    D|1980-01-01|  1|
# |   A|  B|    E|    F|1980-01-01|  2|
# |   G|  H|    C|    D|1980-01-01|  3|
# |   M|  H|    C|    F|1978-06-01|  4|
# |   M|  N|    C|    F|1978-06-01|  5|
# |   M|  N|    X|    F|1978-06-01|  6|
# |   P|  H|    C|    F|1978-06-01|  7|
# +----+---+-----+-----+----------+---+
```

For the above input, the desired output is

```
# +---+---+
# | id|grp|
# +---+---+
# |  1|  1|
# |  2|  1|
# |  3|  1|
# |  4|  2|
# |  5|  2|
# |  6|  2|
# |  7|  2|
# +---+---+
```